# Copy Other Cell to Add to Email with Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have this code to send and email out based on a change in cell a, however i want to have contents of other cells in the email body to more specifically locate the issue for the end user. I could not figure out the best way to target the particular cells i wanted. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect([A2:A1000], Target) Is Nothing Then
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set M = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngBody As Range
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim Issues As String
    Dim Desc As String
    Issues = Target.row


    With ActiveSheet
        'here is where i'm trying to get the contents of "F"
        Desc = Range("F" & Issues)
        Set rngBody = Intersect([A2:A1000], Target)
    End With
    rngBody.Copy

    With M
        .Subject = "Issue Tracker Has Changed"
        .Body = "The Status of Your Issue" & Desc & " Has Changed to " & rngBody
        .Recipients.Add "jane.doe@whatever.org"
        .Send
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Intersect returns a range and thus you have to adapt the values in both issue and rngBody to what you want exactly. If each of these ranges include a single cell, you might put directly issue.Value and rngBody.Value in the .Body part. On the other hand, if there are various cells in each range, each of them containing a word, you might create String variables (for example: issueString and rngBodyString) from a loop interating through all the cell .Value of each range and putting them together separated by " ", for example. What do you want exactly?

Comment: I want to add the text from another cell that describes what has been changed so the end used knows what to look for. For example if the issue has been "Closed" the body will also show what that issue was. Column A has the Status and F has the description and J has their email which i may end up putting in the to field, but that depends on how the users want it to be sent

Comment: The idea is very simple: if the given ranges ("issue" and "rngBody") consist exclusively in a single cell, in ".Body" you have to write "issue.Value" and "rngBody.Value". If there are more than one cell, you would have to create something to adapt the information to what you expect. If you are not about this problem should be faced exactly, please, describe it in as much detail as possible and I can try to come up with something.

Comment: So when i change cell A2 to "closed" i want cell F2's text to write to the email. I'm sure how much more specific you'd like me to be, but basically i want the string data from the matching row when A is changed

Comment: Well... first clarification might be why you cannot take the value of A2 ("closed") directly. Other clarification would be how are your relating cells A2 and F2? Via VBA (Range("F2").Value = Range("A2").Value) or via Excel formula (in F2 wrinting "=A2"). Other clarification might be what is target about? Other clarification would be how many cells are you expecting just one, etc.

Comment: Let me do a new (and last) try: forget about the code and tell clearly and step by step what you want to accomplish exactly. EXAMPLE: I want a code able to read X number of cells; the contents of these cells might be string or integers; I want to check all the inputs in these cells and concatenate them together into one string variable to be assigned to the body of the email. -> pretty clear isn't it? Now try it yourself.

Comment: I want to grab the values of two individual cells from one row. One is declared as rgnbody, this gets the status. the other cell has a description i want them both individually placed in different spots of the body. So it would read in .Body something like this. "The status of your issue, break pads will be delivered next week, has changed to closed. Therefore the two cells will act in a mutually exclusive manner aside from the fact they are located in the same row of the spread sheet

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by taking the row value of Target and combing it with the column I needed the data from and returned it as a string in the body..

```
    Dim Issues As String
    Dim Desc As String
    Issues = Target.row

    Desc = Range("F" & Issues)


.Body = "The Status of Your Issue" & Desc & " Has Changed to " & rngBody.Value
```

by adding these lines i was able to accomplish the issue I had